# Problems executing this INSERT in MS Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

So I seem to be forced to use MS Access as a SQL Server client.

For whatever reason, this just won't execute:

```
INSERT INTO l9990064_INF_PATH (DATA_PATH)
VALUES ("/OlifeRequest/RequestType") 
SELECT DATA_PATH, "/OlifeRequest/RequestType" 
FROM l9990064_INF_PATH 
WHERE DATA_PATH NOT IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT DATA_PATH 
FROM l9990064_INF_PATH 
WHERE DATA_PATH="/OlifeRequest/RequestType");
```

Basically the query attempts to insert a field in table if it doesn't already exist in that table.

The error I get is:

```
Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement.
```

Clearly this is not the case, there is in fact a semicolon at the very end.

It appears to be a valid query so I'm wondering what I have to do here? Thanks!

Comment: I am simply trying to insert data, but not if it already exists in the table. I stated this, what is hard to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know this at first, but it appears the queries I was using would work in SQL server but Access was only allowing Access queries or some shit. So even though Access was acting as a SQL server client, it wasn't really allowing me to use SQL server queries.

I went through the pain of getting SQL Server Management Studio as the client through the painful procurement at my company and I couldn't think of a better solution, do not use Access as a SQL Server client kids...

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO l9990064_INF_PATH (DATA_PATH)
VALUES ('/OlifeRequest/RequestType');   --<-- Single Quotes


SELECT DATA_PATH, '/OlifeRequest/RequestType'    --<-- Single Quotes 
FROM l9990064_INF_PATH 
WHERE DATA_PATH <>  '/OlifeRequest/RequestType';    --<-- Single Quotes
```

Also there is no need to use `NOT IN` operator since it is checking the value in the same table it is selecting from.

Or if you were trying to insert data from a SELECT statement , it would be something like ....

```
INSERT INTO l9990064_INF_PATH (DATA_PATH, Other_Column_Name)
SELECT DATA_PATH, '/OlifeRequest/RequestType'   
FROM l9990064_INF_PATH 
WHERE DATA_PATH <>  '/OlifeRequest/RequestType';
```

Comment: But then the statements would be totally independent? They are meant to be part of the same execution. Executing them separately is useless to me. How do I properly execute a unique insert?

Comment: @Wes your existing query makes no sense to me. You are trying to insert only into the column `data_path` yet you have two different columns in the select, and they can't possibly lead to that value because of the where clause. It is impossible to decipher what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @Aaron I stated "Basically the query attempts to insert a field in table if it doesn't already exist in that table." I understand it is invalid SQL so I was wanting to know what would be proper SQL to achieve that end.

Comment: @Wes `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.tbl WHERE col = 'x') INSERT dbo.tbl(col) VALUES('x');` or `INSERT dbo.tbl(col) SELECT 'x' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.tbl WHERE col = 'x');`

Comment: @Wes simply google for [`Insert Data where not exists`](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=insert+data+when+not+exists&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=BDG0VO_JJ8fjapeSgJAI#q=insert+data+where+not+exists) there are already loads of reference online for that.

Comment: @Ali thats actually what I did apparently the SQL statement I found was invalid.

Comment: @Aaron I get errors executing either of those statements (after adapting them). Did you test them first?

Comment: @Wes Yes, I tested them on my own tables, in SQL Server. Of course I have no idea where you're running them and how well you adapted them. Maybe someone else can provide better help, or you should get a SQL manual.

Comment: @Aaron Well apparently INSERT should be INSERT INTO and the outer SELECT in the second statement should be FROM somewhere? But there is only a WHERE statement. I dunno.

Comment: @Wes That is a lot of attitude from someone seeking help. `INTO` is optional and no, if you are only inserting a single value, you don't need a `FROM` (and in fact you can also do `INSERT ... VALUES('row 1'),('row 2'),etc`) or `'a' UNION SELECT 'b'`. Again, consult a SQL manual. Also maybe try running your queries NOT from inside of Access (I don't know who is forcing you to use Access, or why, but there are other - better - ways to run queries against SQL Server). Who knows what kind of form you're using to do this but the error message in the question is certainly not coming from SQL Server.

Comment: MS Access is acting as a client. I dont know if this means it will execute it as SQL server though, doesn't look like it I guess.